# comparing dates in Javascript - Results not consistent

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check 2 date fields and compare to see which date is ahead, behind or the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789913/how-to-check-2-date-fields-and-compare-to-see-which-date-is-ahead-behind-or-the)

I am trying to implement a validation which should compare two dates and give an alert message.

`entrydate` is a text feild in our ASP page and so is `vdata`. I should check and make sure that `vdata` is always greater than or equal to `entrydate`. The code below is not working.

Please help to identify what the problem is with the this code:

```
if(document.Step2.entrydate.value <= document.all(vData).value)
```

Comment: This is not the solution, but don't use `document.all`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693542/document-documentelement-vs-document-all

Comment: not enough details by far. what does console.log(document.all(vData)) give you?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the text in an input box is just that, text.  You are trying to compare dates, so you will need to convert those strings into dates and compare the dates.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `value` of a textfield is a string. So you're basically comparing strings, and not dates.

You would first need to parse your string into an actual `Date` object before you can do a reliable comparison. How you would do that depends on the format of the data